# vim-jedi autocomplete not working

Tags: python, vim, jedi-vim

I just installed [jedi-vim](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim) with vundle
My vim version is 7.3.429.
I installed jedi vi pip

every time I hit `.` or `<C-Space>` I get this error.

```
Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found
```

when I searched here for this pattern I found a solution to use vim-jedi instead. But unfortunatelly this occours with jedi-vim.

Here is some output of some registers:

`:set omnifunc`

`omnifunc=jedi#complete`

---

`:messages`

```
Messages maintainer: Bram Moolenaar <Bram@vim.org>
"models.py" 31L, 1052C
<emptyline>
```

Comment: Could you rephrase the part with "everytime I hit"

Comment: Please report back `:set omnifunc` and post the output of :messages (after a failed completion).

Comment: I installed jedi-vim also on my work machine and reproduced this error. I updated my question with the output. Hope this will help.

Comment: what's the content of `:messages`? That's much more important :-)

Comment: I updated the question, do you need something more?

Comment: This is really strange... have you tried another machine? Maybe start with a fresh vimrc to debug? Nobody has experienced such issues beside you (afaik).

Comment: For the record, I have this issue also :)

Answer (score 8):

Because this line was in my .vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType python setlocal omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
```

I could not use jedi for a long time. When removed it, it's OK.

```
:set omnifunc
omnifunc=jedi#completions
```

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, jedi-vim was publicly released one or two weeks ago. I doubt you will get much help outside of its issue tracker.

Anyway, the plugin seems to be using Vim's omni completion under the hood, specifically the `<C-x><C-o>` shortcut which, in your case, doesn't seem to return anything because it can't recognize the keyword before the `.`.

Either jedi-vim doesn't work or your code is wrong or the plugin is badly installed.

Comment: Actually there hasn't been an offical "release". I wanted to do a little beta (but how do you do that with open source products :-)).

Comment: "Open source" doesn't mean "do everything publicly from day one": you could develop your project in stealth mode and put it on Github once you have gone through a couple of alpha testing rounds and you feel it's ready for scrutiny. That way you are limiting the risks accidental release on reddit/HN.

Comment: You're certainly right. It wasn't that unplanned. I just didn't want to attract as many people as it did. That's what you cannot control that well. However, Jedi is working fairly well. There are only a few minor problems.